# How to let client application outside your netowrk connect to your server

Tags: sockets, networking

I'm new to socket programming. I have developed fundamental/simple client and server application where client successfully communicates with server. Currently, both the server is on my system (local  host) and client is also my system.

Now I want to somehow allow clients outside the network ( network where my system belongs to) to communicate with the server but i have no idea what to do and how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a smaple code taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-python/#:%7E:text=Socket%20programming%20is%20a%20way,reaches%20out%20to%20the%20server.)

## server.py

```
enter code here
import socket                

# next create a socket object 
s = socket.socket()          
print "Socket successfully created"
port = 12345                
s.bind(('', port))         
print "socket binded to %s" %(port) 
s.listen(5)      
print "socket is listening"            
while True: 

  # Establish connection with client. 
  c, addr = s.accept()      
  print 'Got connection from', addr 
  c.send('Thank you for connecting') 
  c.close()
```

## client.py

```
  import socket                 
   s = socket.socket()          
   port = 12345                 
   s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port)) 
   print s.recv(1024) 
   s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t really need to change anything in your code, except for the IP that the client connects to.  It needs to be the server PC’s public Internet IP instead of `127.0.0.1`.

If the server PC is connected *directly* to the Internet modem, then you are done.

Otherwise, if the server PC is behind a router or proxy, then you need to configure **port forwarding** on that router/proxy to forward traffic from its public WAN IP/port to the server PC’s LAN IP/port. Consult your router/proxy’s documentation for how to do that configuration.

If the router/proxy has uPNP enabled, your server code can dynamically forward the WAN IP/port to itself at runtime.  See [Python: Open a Listening Port Behind a Router (upnp?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391872/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, What you said makes sense but I'm scared of messing up my router's setting. I have Upnp setting option in my router, if i enable it does router automatically allow client apps outside network to connect to my server ?

Comment: @blacksheep369 you won’t mess up anything in the router by configuring port forwarding on it. However, if uPnp is enabled, the router will not *automatically* allow clients to connect to the server, that is not what uPnp does, but it will allow your server code to use the uPNP protocol to setup the port forwarding dynamically at runtime, ie after opening the listening port and before entering the accept loop. Then you won’t have to go into the router setup manually.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! this seems to be working but I was wondering how would thelatter approach work ( enabling upnp in router and then updating the code). if you could point me to any articles or tutorials on this it would be of great help! Thanks once again for the help

Comment: yeah I tried tis but unfortunately  miniupnpc lib seems to be missing some modules because of which one gets error while pip installing the library

Comment: @blacksheep369 then you will just have to find another implementation. Or write your own. The *concept* is the same, you just need to a working *implementation*. And that I can't help you with.